# epstopdf suddenly stopped working

Tags: pdftex, miktex, winedt, epstopdf

I'm trying to compile some `.tex` files in WinEdt 7 with pdfLaTeX using MikTex 2.9. I have a lot of eps figures and was previously using `epstopdf` in the preamble without any problems. But for some reason when i try and recompile the `.tex` files (after deleting the converted PDFs) i'm getting the error:

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File 'subFolder_Name/Figure_Name-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

For some reason the `.eps` source file is not getting converted into a PDF. I'm baffled because this was working fine previously and I haven't changed anything with the WinEdt setup.

Any help would be great.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: I have experienced the same problem... I wondered if you found a solution. I have tried some solutions such as using --shell-escape option but it didnt work. In any case it could be that I am not configuring it correctly in winedt. I would highly appreciate any orientation about this problem.thanks
arantxa

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it seems that it is due to some path problem. The solution is to add

```
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}
```

to the LaTeX header. This will cause `epstopdf` to generate files in the specified `.aux` directory instead of the directory of the images (which it does if you would have run texify from the command line).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered problems using epstopdf with texlive on a mac. I've searched tens of forums to look for solutions. The most common problem seems to be that the compiling path isn't set up correctly. However, for me, I just found out that somehow i've not installed ghostscript on my mac. After installing the latest ghostscript, everything works.